# Emitting events into a React Dom

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, webvr

I would like to emit synthetic mouse events (mouseDown, mouseMove, mouseUp) into a React dom. I have tried both native browser events and React Synthetic Events.

```
function emitEvent(eventName, args){
    console.log("clientX:" + args.clientX + " clientY:" + args.clientY);

    let node = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(component);
    let event = new MouseEvent(eventName, extend({
        'view': window,
        'target': node,
        'bubbles': true,
        'composed': true,
        'cancelable': true
    }, args));
    node.dispatchEvent(event);


    // ReactTestUtils.Simulate[eventName](node, extend({
    //     'view': window,
    //     'target': node,
    //     'bubbles': true,
    //     'composed': true,
    //     'cancelable': true
    // }, args));
}
```

What I am trying to do is generate events in WebVR that trigger changes in the DOM. In WebVR I compute the mouse coordinates where I would like to cause the event to occur. I can't determine what element is below the mouse coordinates and I want the browser to figure this out for me.

using node.dispatchEvent I can send events like 'mousedown' down the tree, and if I explicitly register handlers, they do get fired....

However, I can't seem to cause any changes to occur in the UI. 
What I want to be able to do is full mouse interactions, so changing tabs, moving slider etc.. from VR.

Any ideas?

Note: I am using MaterialUI.

Comment: Please take a [look at this comment](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3249#issuecomment-177750141), maybe this will do the job. I can see this is a common issue without a proper solution. The source of the issues might be dead-code elimination in the production build (try on the development build then) and/or browser security. Also, take a look at [react-trigger-change](https://github.com/vitalyq/react-trigger-change)(might not be sufficient for your use case).

Comment: A colleague suggested the following:

        `let element = document.elementFromPoint(args.clientX, args.clientY);
        element.dispatchEvent(event);`



Now our face events do hit something in the react dom tree. I  can move sliders, but I can't change tabs.